# Range Seek bar Custom view with accessibility

Tags: android, accessibility, android-custom-view

I've created a custom range seek bar and I would like to implement accessibility for it. The normal gesture to move the ball to the right/up in the default seek bar is "Right then left". So when the user has the focus on the left ball I want to detect the "Right then left" gesture when the talkback is on and move the ball one step.

You can activate the talkback and use the volume as an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

**Talkback gestures information:**
[URL](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6151827?hl=en)

[image: My custom range seek bar]

```
public class MyRangeSeekBar extends ConstraintLayout implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private static final String TAG = MyRangeSeekBar.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final long BALL_SPEED = 300;
    private static final int STEPS_LIMIT = 2;
    private static final int STEPS_MAX = 10;
    private final MyRangeSeekBarBinding binding;
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH);
    private int min = 1;
    private int max = 10;
    private int currentMin = 1;
    private int currentMax = 10;
    private float dX;
    private float posInitBar;
    private float posEndBar;
    private float halfBallWidth;
    private float barWidth;
    private float segmentWidth;
    private int rangeDescriptionLabel;
    private int rangeJoinDescriptionLabel;
    private int minimumDescriptionLabel;
    private int maximumDescriptionLabel;
    private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##", symbols);

    public MyRangeSeekBar(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MyRangeSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyRangeSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        binding = MyRangeSeekBarBinding.inflate(inflater, this, true);
        initAttrs(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void initAttrs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        final TypedArray attributes =
                context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                        attrs,
                        R.styleable.MyRangeSeekBar,
                        defStyleAttr,
                        0);
        min = attributes.getInt(R.styleable.MyRangeSeekBar_min, 1);
        max = attributes.getInt(R.styleable.MyRangeSeekBar_max, 10);
        currentMin = attributes.getInt(R.styleable.MyRangeSeekBar_currentMin, 1);
        currentMax = attributes.getInt(R.styleable.MyRangeSeekBar_currentMax, 10);
        rangeDescriptionLabel = attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyRangeSeekBar_rangeDescriptionLabel, R.string.mcaiucomps_range_label);
        rangeJoinDescriptionLabel = attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyRangeSeekBar_rangeJoinDescriptionLabel, R.string.mcaiucomps_range_join_label);
        minimumDescriptionLabel = attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyRangeSeekBar_minimumDescriptionLabel, R.string.mcaiucomps_min_label);
        maximumDescriptionLabel = attributes.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyRangeSeekBar_maximumDescriptionLabel, R.string.mcaiucomps_max_label);

        attributes.recycle();

        refresh();
    }

    private void checkValues() {
        if (max - min < STEPS_LIMIT) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not enough steps, you need a minimum of 2 steps like from 1 to 3");
        }
        if (max - min >= STEPS_MAX) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Too many steps, you can't do more than 10 steps");
        }
        if (currentMin < min || currentMin > max) {
            throw new RuntimeException("The minimum value is not between the limits");
        }
        if (currentMax < min || currentMax > max) {
            throw new RuntimeException("The maximum value is not between the limits");
        }
        if (currentMin > currentMax) {
            throw new RuntimeException("The minimum is bigger than the maximum value");
        }
    }

    private void setBar() {

        binding.mcaiucompsBar.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                halfBallWidth = binding.mcaiucompsBallLeft.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
                posInitBar = binding.mcaiucompsBar.getX() + halfBallWidth;
                posEndBar = binding.mcaiucompsBar.getMeasuredWidth() - halfBallWidth;

                binding.mcaiucompsBallRight.setX(posEndBar + halfBallWidth);
                binding.mcaiucompsBallLeft.setX(posInitBar + halfBallWidth);

                barWidth = posEndBar - posInitBar;
                segmentWidth = barWidth / (max - min);

                setBalls();
            }
        });
    }

    private void setTitles() {
        binding.mcaiucompsMinValue.setText(getContext().getString(minimumDescriptionLabel, min));
        binding.mcaiucompsMinValue.setContentDescription(getContext().getString(minimumDescriptionLabel, min) + ", " + getContext().getString(R.string.caixabank_componente_rango_minimo));
        binding.mcaiucompsMaxValue.setText(getContext().getString(maximumDescriptionLabel, max));
        binding.mcaiucompsMaxValue.setContentDescription(getContext().getString(maximumDescriptionLabel, max) + ", " + getContext().getString(R.string.caixabank_componente_rango_maximo));
        binding.mcaiucompsTitle.setText(getContext().getString(rangeDescriptionLabel, currentMin, currentMax));
        binding.mcaiucompsTitle.setContentDescription(getContext().getString(rangeDescriptionLabel, currentMin, currentMax));
    }

    private void updateBallsPosition(View view) {
        //Check limits
        if (binding.mcaiucompsBallLeft.getId() == view.getId() && getLeftBallPos() < posInitBar) {
            animateBall(view, posInitBar);
        } else if (binding.mcaiucompsBallRight.getId() == view.getId() && getRightBallPos() > posEndBar) {
            animateBall(view, posEndBar);
        } else {
            //Move to the closest position
            if (view.getId() == binding.mcaiucompsBallLeft.getId()) {
                if (getLeftBallPos() >= posInitBar) {
                    currentMin = Math.round(getLeftBallPos() / segmentWidth);
                } else if (getLeftBallPos() >= getRightBallPos()) {
                    currentMin = currentMax;
                } else {
                    currentMin = min;
                }

                animateBall(binding.mcaiucompsBallLeft, currentMin * segmentWidth + posInitBar);
            } else {
                if (getRightBallPos() < barWidth) {
                    currentMax = Math.round(getRightBallPos() / segmentWidth);
                } else if (getRightBallPos() >= getLeftBallPos()) {
                    currentMax = currentMin;
                } else {
                    currentMax = max - min;
                }

                animateBall(binding.mcaiucompsBallRight, currentMax * segmentWidth + posInitBar);
            }
        }
    }

    private void animateBall(View view, float pos) {
        pos = Float.parseFloat(df.format(pos));
        // Leave some space between balls if they are in the same position
        if (view.getId() == binding.mcaiucompsBallLeft.getId()
                && (pos <= getRightBallPos() && pos >= getRightBallPos() - halfBallWidth || pos >= posEndBar)) {
            binding.mcaiucompsBallLeft.animate()
                    .x(getRightBallPos() - halfBallWidth * 1.7f)
                    .setDuration(BALL_SPEED)
                    .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
                    .setUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                            changeBarHighlightSize();
                            updateTitle();
                        }
                    })
                    .start();
        } else if (view.getId() == binding.mcaiucompsBallRight.getId()
                && (pos >= getLeftBallPos() && pos <= getLeftBallPos() + halfBallWidth || pos <= posInitBar)) {
            binding.mcaiucompsBallRight.animate()
                    .x(getLeftBallPos() - halfBallWidth * 0.3f)
                    .setDuration(BALL_SPEED)
                    .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
                    .setUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                            changeBarHighlightSize();
                            updateTitle();
                        }
                    })
                    .start();

        } else {
            view.animate()
                    .x(pos - halfBallWidth)
                    .setDuration(BALL_SPEED)
                    .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator())
                    .setUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                            changeBarHighlightSize();
                            updateTitle();
                        }
                    })
                    .start();
        }
    }

    private void updateTitle() {
        int minLabel = Math.round((getLeftBallPos() - posInitBar) / segmentWidth) + min;
        int maxLabel = Math.round((getRightBallPos() - posInitBar) / segmentWidth) + min;

        if (getRightBallPos() == posEndBar || maxLabel > max) {
            maxLabel = max;
        }
        if (getLeftBallPos() == posInitBar || minLabel < min) {
            minLabel = min;
        }
        String title = getContext().getString(rangeDescriptionLabel, minLabel, maxLabel);
        if (minLabel == maxLabel) {
            title = getContext().getString(rangeJoinDescriptionLabel, minLabel);
        }
        binding.mcaiucompsTitle.setText(title);
        binding.mcaiucompsTitle.setContentDescription(title);


    }

    private float getLeftBallPos() {
        return Float.parseFloat(df.format(binding.mcaiucompsBallLeft.getX() + halfBallWidth));
    }

    private float getRightBallPos() {
        return Float.parseFloat(df.format(binding.mcaiucompsBallRight.getX() + halfBallWidth));
    }

    private void setBalls() {
        binding.mcaiucompsBallLeft.setOnTouchListener(this);
        binding.mcaiucompsBallRight.setOnTouchListener(this);

        float posMin = (currentMin - min) * segmentWidth + posInitBar;
        float posMax = (currentMax - min) * segmentWidth + posInitBar;
        if (currentMax == currentMin) {
            posMin = posMax + halfBallWidth - halfBallWidth * 1.7f;
        }
        animateBall(binding.mcaiucompsBallLeft, posMin);
        animateBall(binding.mcaiucompsBallRight, posMax);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (binding.mcaiucompsBallLeft.getId() == view.getId()
                || binding.mcaiucompsBallRight.getId() == view.getId()) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    dX = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
                    view.bringToFront();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (isValidMove(view, event.getRawX() + dX)) {
                        view.animate()
                                .x(event.getRawX() + dX)
                                .setDuration(0)
                                .start();
                        changeBarHighlightSize();
                        updateTitle();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onTouch: " + event.getRawX() + " dx: " + dX);
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    updateBallsPosition(view);
                    break;

                default:
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isValidMove(View view, float rawX) {
        if ((binding.mcaiucompsBallLeft.getId() == view.getId() && getLeftBallPos() >= posInitBar)
                || (binding.mcaiucompsBallRight.getId() == view.getId() && getRightBallPos() <= posEndBar)) {
            if ((binding.mcaiucompsBallLeft.getId() == view.getId() && rawX + halfBallWidth / 2 <= binding.mcaiucompsBallRight.getX())
                    || (binding.mcaiucompsBallRight.getId() == view.getId() && rawX + halfBallWidth / 2 >= getLeftBallPos())) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void changeBarHighlightSize() {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = binding.mcaiucompsBarHighlight.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = (int) (getRightBallPos() - getLeftBallPos());
        binding.mcaiucompsBarHighlight.setLayoutParams(params);

        binding.mcaiucompsBarHighlight.setX(getLeftBallPos());


    }

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public void setMin(int min) {
        this.min = min;
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(int max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    public int getCurrentMin() {
        return currentMin;
    }

    public void setCurrentMin(int currentMin) {
        this.currentMin = currentMin;
    }

    public int getCurrentMax() {
        return currentMax;
    }

    public void setCurrentMax(int currentMax) {
        this.currentMax = currentMax;
    }

    public void setRangeDescriptionLabel(@StringRes int rangeDescriptionLabel) {
        this.rangeDescriptionLabel = rangeDescriptionLabel;
        updateTitle();
    }

    public void setRangeJoinDescriptionLabel(@StringRes int rangeJoinDescriptionLabel) {
        this.rangeJoinDescriptionLabel = rangeJoinDescriptionLabel;
        updateTitle();
    }

    public void setMinimumDescriptionLabel(@StringRes int minimumDescriptionLabel) {
        this.minimumDescriptionLabel = minimumDescriptionLabel;
        setTitles();
    }

    public void setMaximumDescriptionLabel(@StringRes int maximumDescriptionLabel) {
        this.maximumDescriptionLabel = maximumDescriptionLabel;
        setTitles();
    }

    public void refresh() {
        checkValues();
        setBar();
        setTitles();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(View child, AccessibilityEvent event) {
        return super.onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent(child, event);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "move the ball one step", do you mean that you want the focus to go from the first ball to the second, and this isn't happening at the moment? Please add the code for the seekbar.

Comment: I meant to move the left ball to the next number like is doing the normal seekbar with accessibility

Comment: There's no numbers in the picture. I am confused, can you add the code for this custom view?

Comment: @ataulm It doesn't enter in the method "onRequestSendAccessibilityEvent" when I do the gesture "left then right", but it works with all the other gestures. So it's like I have to add that action to the imageview(ball) but I can't figure out

Comment: Ah I see, I'm not sure to be honest. It looks like the event type you're looking for is `TYPE_VIEW_SCROLLED` but the docs say that this event is not usually sent "directly". I wonder if this means you need to detect this behaviour yourself for each of the balls.